# Can't get Javascript UI watchdog functions to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, qtip

So this question should be really basic, but I can't find anything specifically related to it online or on Stack Exchange.
I'm running to run some DOM in my .js file to replace JavaScript function calls within the HTML and to use Qtip for tool tip implementation. However, I cannot get even the most basic of scripts to run for this function. Here's some code snippet:

```
<body>
<div id="title_Bar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DOMscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here's the code for DOMscript.js:

```
$('#title_Bar').mouseover(function() {
alert("hello");
}
```

I've already called Jquery in the header because I use it in most of the other scripts I'm running which are all working just fine, but I can't get the mouseover or hover or any of the other neat UI JavaScript tricks working.

I tried loading DOMscript.js in the header with the rest of my scripts and that didn't work either. I want these watchdog functions to be running constantly but not interfering with the functionality of the page overall, so any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in your js file.

Comment: Sigh... I'm an idiot. -___-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note down the correction;

```
$('#title_Bar').mouseover(function() {alert("hello");});
```

closing parenthesis were missing in you code.

Answer (score 1):

Ya'll might want the .hover function instead...

```
$("#title_Bar").hover( function () {
  alert("Mouse is entering the element");
}, function() {
  alert("Mouse done up and left the element");
});
```

... i made a [little jsfiddle with it too](http://jsfiddle.net/749qmxnc/)